# How to Copy a row conditionally to another sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I read all of other questions but I didn't get it.
I have a dataset where each row represents a data entry.
My table looks like this in excel:

**Q:** How can I copy rows to another sheet where these criterias fit: Female, Undergraduate, under 20?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways to go:

- Set an **Autofilter** on the data via the `Sort and Filter`->`Filter` selections from the Home tab of the ribbon. Then, use the dropdown menus at the top of each column to select either s a specific value for the criterion (Female) or a condition using a number filter "less than 20". Then manually copy and paste the filtered data to a new location or worksheet.

*Setting the Gender column to "Female"*

[image]

*Adding a number filter for the "Age" column*

[image]

- Set an **Advanced** filter on the data via the `Sort and Filter` group on the `Data` tab of the ribbon. This requires you set up a criterion range on the worksheet and prompts you for a location to put the filtered data.

[image]